# PIC code does not compile

Tags: c++, c, pic

I need quick advice for this code it does not compile and i cant figure out whats wrong with it. I am just trying to print the elements in the array in PORT C which is my output port. Thanks

```
#include <htc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 500000 

void main()
       {
    int x[8]={0b1110, 0b1010, 0b1000, 0b1001, 0b0001, 0b0101, 0b0111, 0b0110, 0b1110};
    int i,PORTC;
    TRISC = 0 ;     // set PORTC as OUTPUT
    PORTC = 0b0000;
    for(;;){         // forever 
                 for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){
                 PORTC = n[ i ] = i + 1; /* set element at location i to i + 1 */
                 __delay_ms(500);   }       

            }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error that the compiler gives?

Comment: Are you sure it's n[ i ] = i + 1 and not x[ i ] = i + 1?

Comment: You shouldn't use 16-bit int on those 8-bit microcontrollers. Declare `char x[8]; char i` instead. And your indentation is bad

Comment: It should be x[] or x[9].

Answer (score 1):

You reference `n[ i ]`, when you apparently mean `x[ i ]`.

Comment: if `n` is really `x` then it isn't needed anymore. Just `PORTC = i + 1;` is enough. He should remove the array declaration above

Comment: or if he needs to output the array's value then use `PORTC = x[1]`, the assignment will override the initialized values

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't declare `PORTC` as a local `int`, it's supposed to be a special "variable" that mirrors the hardware register. You might need some processor-specific include(s) too, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of someone who actually knows something about the PIC, I suggest you try something like this:

```
void main() {
  int x[8]={0b1110, 0b1010, 0b1000, 0b1001, 0b0001, 0b0101, 0b0111, 0b0110, 0b1110};
  int i;
  TRISC = 0;
  PORTC = 0b0000;
  for(;;) {
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      PORTC = x[i];
      __delay_ms(500);   }       
    }
  }
}
```

TRISC is the control port for PORTC. A value of zero sets all pins on PORTC to be output ports. [thanks - see comment]

PORTC is an input/output port. I assume it's hooked up to a display of some kind. With the proper setting of TRISC it should act as an output port.

This should output 8 values at half-second intervals from the table to the port and repeat forever. Kind of "hello world" for microprocessors.

Comment: Just for completeness: `TRISC = 0` sets all the pins on I/O port C to be outputs.